# How to split an image with offset using ImageMagic?

Tags: command-line, images, imagemagick, split, image-manipulation

I planning to print a large map(**6400x15360**) and I want to split that image to multiple images(**1123x794**).
I found that `-crop 1123x794` do that but How I can add offset so it will be easier for me to glue the pages after the print?

Comment: You don't need an offset. `convert` will divide the image into tiles of the size given in `-crop`.

Comment: Also: https://askubuntu.com/a/143501/158442

Comment: @muru What if i want an offset?

Comment: Add a `+x+y` to the crop dimension. See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop But given your reason "so it will be easier for me to glue the pages", I don't see why you want one.

Comment: @muru when I do "convert -crop 1123x794+30+30 test.png test\%d.png", it just give the first image and stop.